# Why am I able to compile with a dll but not a static library?

Tags: opengl, gcc, dll, glfw, lib

I am following an OpenGL tutorial (on Windows). I am trying to use glfw to create a graphics context but am not able to get the static library I downloaded to link to my source code. If I instead use the glfw dll, everything works and I can run my program, but I would rather not have a run-time dependency on the glfw dll.

My current directory structure looks like this:

```
root_folder:
    externs:
        GLFW:
            glfw3.lib
            glfw3.h
            glfw3native.h
    window.c
```

I compile my code with this command:

`gcc window.c -o window.exe -L externs/GLFW -lglfw3 -lopengl32`

However, when I do this, I get this nasty (and heinously long) output:

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.text$mn+0x29e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glfwCreateWindow]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.text$mn+0x286): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.text$mn+0x790): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glfwUpdateGamepadMappings]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$parseMapping]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x73): undefined reference to `__imp___stdio_common_vsprintf'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x327): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInputError]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x3be): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwRefreshContextAttribs]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x50): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x1a7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x50): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x1cb): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x84): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x3ec): more undefined references to `__security_check_cookie' follow
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0xcb): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x10f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateBitmap'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x131): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x1d3): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x1dc): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x20d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x36e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x91): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x8e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x67): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x50): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateRectRgn'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0xd6): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x167): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x76a): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowPos]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetWindowSize]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowSize]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowSizeLimits]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowAspectRatio]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetFramebufferSize]+0xc): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x57): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x69): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x38): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x49): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x52): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x196): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x5b): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x6d): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x82): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x91): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x9b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x207): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x45): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x19a): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x1ab): undefined reference to `__imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x1b4): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x1cc): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x2f3): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x17f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0xa8): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0xcc): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0xdd): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x10c): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x141): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x162): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x2c0): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0xb7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPollMonitorsWin32]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwSetVideoModeWin32]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetMonitorPos]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetMonitorWorkarea]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetVideoModes]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetVideoMode]+0x14): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x1d3): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x10e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x233): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x39b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x60): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x518): more undefined references to `__security_check_cookie' follow
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitJoysticksWin32]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwDetectJoystickConnectionWin32]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwDetectJoystickDisconnectionWin32]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformPollJoystick]+0x28): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformUpdateGamepadGUID]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$deviceObjectCallback]+0x10): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0xe7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x97): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0xbc): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x3bc): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x1d2): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x48): more undefined references to `__security_check_cookie' follow
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwIsWindowsVersionOrGreaterWin32]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwIsWindows10BuildOrGreaterWin32]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInputErrorWin32]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwUpdateKeyNamesWin32]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformInit]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$loadLibraries]+0x8): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x21b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x4c): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x1cd): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitOSMesa]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwCreateContextOSMesa]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x4b7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x49): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x534): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitEGL]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwCreateContextEGL]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x94): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0xc2): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x447): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x2d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x6c): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x17c): undefined reference to `__imp_ChoosePixelFormat'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x18c): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x3a3): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x158): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x61c): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x77f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x81): undefined reference to `__imp_SwapBuffers'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitWGL]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwCreateContextWGL]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
externs/GLFW/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$choosePixelFormat]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Just for kicks, I replaced glfw3.lib with glfw3.dll (which came in the same download). If I run the same compilation command, gcc successfully produces window.exe which, if I copy glfw3.dll to root_folder, creates a window as expected. This is fine for now, but obviously I don't love having to have glfw.dll at run-time, especially in my top level directory.

Here's the code in window.c, but I doubt it has any relevance to my issue (it's exactly the starter code on the [GLFW website](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) with the include path adjusted for my directory structure):

```
#include "externs/GLFW/glfw3.h"

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I've done some googling and it sounds like the .lib file also requires that I link with other windows libraries (the internet suggests linking with user32 even though I am compiling for 64 bit), but adding `-luser32` to my compilation does not seem to help. What I don't understand is why the dll does not seem to have this issue. It seems to me that I should either need to link with windows libraries in both cases or not at all. How can I resolve the additional dependencies from the static library?

Also (this is a side question that's more just to satisfy my curiosity, not really part of the actual question in this post), why must I have glfw3.dll in the same folder as my executable in order to run it? Surely this is not a general requirement -- is there a flag I can add to gcc to specify where it should look for dlls at run-time?

I'm hoping this is a relatively simple issue to fix, I use gcc to compile my assignments at school but this is my first time trying to link with external libraries so there's a good chance I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks so much!

Update: the tutorial just had me add GLEW and I get the same type of issue; I can run with the GLEW dll but if I try to link with the static library I get a bunch of errors when I try to link.

Comment: You neither compile with a dll nor a static library. A (static or dynamic) library is linked. For the use of GLFW in a dll the preprocessor definition `GLFW_DLL` has to be defined. See [GLFW - With MinGW or Visual C++ on Windows](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html#build_link_win32).

Comment: Are you saying you can't run the program without the DLL, or you can't compile it, i.e. the compiler gives you an error?

Comment: @Chipster if I choose to link with the dll, I am able to run my program. If I instead try to link with a static library, I get all of the errors included in my post.